# How to find usage of non-public API in Mac Qt App

Tags: macos, qt, webkit, app-store, qtwebkit

Our qtwebkit-based application is rejected by apple after submission to mac app store. One of the reasons for rejection is the usage of non-public API. I've managed found six of them in the source code for qtwebkit. But I have no where to find the rest. I searched through the source code of our application and the entire source code of QT.

The six non-public api I found in qtwebkit source is:

```
CFHTTPCookieStorageSetCookieAcceptPolicy
CFURLCacheCopyResponseForRequest
CFURLResponseGetMIMEType
CFURLResponseCopySuggestedFilename
CFURLCacheSetMemoryCapacity
CFURLCacheSetDiskCapacity
```

Here is the full list of violations found by apple:

> The use of non-public APIs can lead to a poor user experience should
>   these APIs change in the future, and is therefore not permitted. The
>   following non-public APIs are included in your application:
>
> NSAccessibilityCreateAXUIElementRef 
>   NSAccessibilityHandleFocusChanged 
>   NSAccessibilityUnregisterUniqueIdForUIElement  NSAppKitPropertyCreator
>   NSCarbonWindowPropertyTag  NSMouseMovedNotification 
>   _NSDrawCarbonThemeBezel  _NSDrawCarbonThemeListBox  _NSPopUpCarbonMenu3  _NXShowKeyAndMain  from the framework: '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit'
>
> AXTextMarkerCreate  AXTextMarkerGetBytePtr  AXTextMarkerGetLength 
>   AXTextMarkerGetTypeID  AXTextMarkerRangeCopyEndMarker 
>   AXTextMarkerRangeCopyStartMarker  AXTextMarkerRangeCreate 
>   AXTextMarkerRangeGetTypeID  CTLineCreateWithUniCharProvider 
>   CoreDragGetCurrentDrag  CoreDragSetImage  from the framework:
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices'
>
> GetNativeWindowFromWindowRef  TSMGetInputSourceProperty  from the
>   framework:
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon'
>
> CFReadStreamSignalEvent  _CFAppVersionCheckLessThan 
>   _CFBundleSetDefaultLocalization  _CFStringGetUserDefaultEncoding  from the framework:
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation'
>
> CFHTTPCookieStorageCopyCookiesForURL  CFHTTPCookieStorageDeleteCookie
>   CFHTTPCookieStorageGetCookieAcceptPolicy 
>   CFHTTPCookieStorageSetCookieAcceptPolicy 
>   CFHTTPCookieStorageSetCookies  CFURLCacheCopyResponseForRequest 
>   CFURLCacheSetDiskCapacity  CFURLCacheSetMemoryCapacity 
>   CFURLRequestCreateMutableCopy  CFURLResponseCopySuggestedFilename 
>   CFURLResponseGetExpectedContentLength  CFURLResponseGetHTTPResponse 
>   CFURLResponseGetMIMEType  CFURLResponseGetURL 
>   CFURLResponseSetExpectedContentLength  CFURLResponseSetMIMEType 
>   _CFNetworkHTTPConnectionCacheGetLimit  _CFNetworkHTTPConnectionCacheSetLimit  _CFURLCacheCopyCacheDirectory  _CFURLRequestCreateArchiveList  _CFURLRequestCreateFromArchiveList  _CFURLResponseCreateArchiveList  _CFURLResponseCreateFromArchiveList  _CFURLResponseGetSSLCertificateContext  _LSGetCurrentApplicationASN  _LSSetApplicationInformationItem  _kLSDisplayNameKey  kCFStreamPropertyCONNECTAdditionalHeaders 
>   kCFStreamPropertyCONNECTProxy  kCFStreamPropertyCONNECTProxyHost 
>   kCFStreamPropertyCONNECTProxyPort  kCFStreamPropertyCONNECTResponse 
>   kCFURLResponseExpectedContentLengthUnknown  from the framework:
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices'
>
> NSPopAutoreleasePool  NSPushAutoreleasePool  from the framework:
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation'
>
> CARenderCGDestroy  CARenderCGNew  CARenderCGRender 
>   CARenderNotificationAddObserver  CARenderNotificationRemoveObserver 
>   CARenderServerGetPort  CARenderServerStart  CARenderUpdateAddContext 
>   CARenderUpdateAddRect  CARenderUpdateBegin  CARenderUpdateFinish 
>   kCAContextPortNumber  from the framework:
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore'
>
> If you have defined methods in your source code with the same names as
>   the above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so
>   that they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your
>   application being flagged in future submissions.
>
> Additionally, one or more of the above-mentioned APIs may reside in a
>   library included with your application. If you do not have access to
>   the library's source, you may be able to search the compiled binary
>   using "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can
>   output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov"
>   will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined
>   methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the
>   problematic code resides.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning which version of Qt you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I've finally traced down to the location where these so-called privatate apis are called. They are called from inside webkit. webkit uses a webkit system interface library which is directly supplied from apple in the format of compiled static library+header file. More specifically, they are the four files located under the path src\3rdparty\webkit\WebKitLibraries:

libWebKitSystemInterfaceLeopard.a
libWebKitSystemInterfaceLion.a
libWebKitSystemInterfaceMountainLion.a
libWebKitSystemInterfaceSnowLeopard.a

I always wondered if it's really a private api, who else would know how to call it without any documentation? Now it's turned out to be apple itself. Since neither nokia or digia has the source code to these libraries, there is probably nothing they can do about it.

Now isn't it ironic that any qtwebkit-based apps will be rejected by apple due to private api access from libraries created?

Please correct me if I am wrong or miss anything. I really hope I am wrong.

Comment: Which version of QT are you building against?

Comment: Did you ever get your app approved?